# Get clean column value from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using data from the SQL - converted to dictionary and I need to take a clean value of a specified column. The code I am using at the moment:

```
client_data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql_query((open('query.sql').read()), dbcon))
client_data = client_data.to_dict(orient='dict')
client_name = str(client_data['<client_name>'])
print(client_name)
```

And the outcome is:

```
{0: 'SOME VALUE'}
```

I would need it to be just "SOME VALUE" is it possible without replacing the "{0: '" & "'}" symbols?

```
for k, v in client_data.items():
```

How to get a clean key value from the client_data dictionary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just access it using the key, which in this case is `0`. Something like `client_name.get(0)` should work.

Comment: Its not clear to me how your data is exactly structured. Does `client_name[0]` (using the key `0`of the dictionary)  solve your problem? Maybe post a sample data for clarification.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Thanks! I can't use it on a string value but I can convert it to a string afterward. Thank you a lot!